# How to continue a map on a new line

Tags: python

I'm currently making a very simple program that is supposed to have a map of all 50 states and their corresponding capitals. The goal is to be able to input a state and then have it return said state's capital. I want to be able to do this without writing one long continuous line of code.

I've tried finding solutions like adding an _ or \ at the end of the code, which works great for strings, but it won't work here.

Here is what I have so far:

```
states = {'Alabama':'Montgomery','Alaska':'Juneau','Arizona':'Phoenix','Arkansas':'Little Rock'}
{'California':'Sacramento'}

print(states['Alabama'])
```

You can see that when I hit California:Sacramento I want to continue it on that new line. How can I do this without making a separate map?

Comment: You can put a new line in a dictionary literal after any of the commas.

Comment: You can add a line break inside pretty much any literal, `()`, `[]`, `{}`, `"""multi line string"""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the syntax, newlines within a parenthesised expression do not require a continuation character.

Beyond that, the examples in the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) show a 4-character indentation -- the same as the indentation used for code blocks -- and recommend that the final `}` be aligned either with the start of the statement, like this:

```
states = {
    'Alabama': 'Montgomery',
    'Alaska': 'Juneau',
    'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
    'Arkansas': 'Little Rock',
    'California': 'Sacramento',
}
```

or with last line of the contents, like this:

```
states = {
    'Alabama': 'Montgomery',
    'Alaska': 'Juneau',
    'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
    'Arkansas': 'Little Rock',
    'California': 'Sacramento',
    }
```

It is also worth considering the use of an optional final `,` (as used here after `'Sacramento'`) as it makes it easier to add more items without having to treat the final one as a special case.  Again, the examples in PEP8 have this.

Answer (score 5):

You can add line breaks inside `{…}` without issue:

```
states = {
  'Alabama': 'Montgomery',
  'Alaska': 'Juneau',
  'Arizona': 'Phoenix',
  'Arkansas': 'Little Rock'
}
```

The same is true inside `(…)` and `[…]`. You only need an explicit line continuation via `\` when you’re outside a parenthesised expression.

Comment: Thank you! Not really sure why this is getting downvoted so much but I appreciate it a lot. I'm really new to Python.

Answer (score 2):

```
states = {
'Alabama':'Montgomery',
'Alaska':'Juneau',
'Arizona':'Phoenix',
'Arkansas':'Little Rock',
'California':'Sacramento'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just go down a line:

```py
a = {'a':'A',
     'b':'B',
     'c':'C'}

print(a)
```

result:
`{'a': 'A', 'b': 'B', 'c': 'C'}`